# Как добавить поле select в модуль «Текстовый блок» в opencart 2?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, cms, opencart

В модуль "Текстовый блок - HTML" нужно добавить возможность выбора тега заголовка. Единственное, что у меня пока получилось вывести это поле в админке: 
[image: Админка]

Сделал я это добавив в файл шаблона модуля в админке следующий код:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-tag">Уровень заголовка</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="tag" id="input-tag" class="form-control">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">H1</option>
      <option value="2">H2</option>
      <option value="3">H3</option>
      <option value="4">H4</option>
      <option value="5">H5</option>
      <option value="6">H6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите дальше что делать? Я новичок в этой теме)) Как я понимаю надо получить значение поля в файле контроллере, но не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['tag'])) {
        $data['tag'] = $this->request->post['tag'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info['tag'])) {
        $data['tag'] = $module_info['tag'];
    } else {
        $data['tag'] = '';
    }
```

также добавь:

```
$data['tags']=[
            ['value'=>1,'name'=>'H1'],
            ['value'=>2,'name'=>'H2'],
            ['value'=>3,'name'=>'H3'],
            ['value'=>4,'name'=>'H4'],
            ['value'=>5,'name'=>'H5'],
            ['value'=>6,'name'=>'H6']
        ];
```

В шаблоне:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-tag">Уровень заголовка</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="tag" id="input-tag" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($tags as $item){ ?>
        <?php if($item['value']==$tag){?>
          <option value="<?php echo $item['value']; ?>" selected><?php echo $item['name']; ?></option>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item['value']; ?>"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```